# I cannot get to link a shared library with another using cmake

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, shared-libraries

I am new with `CMake` and i am trying to experiment stuff with it.
Here i am trying to link a shared library `renderHeader` to another shared library `test`.
I have following code samples:

### test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.hpp"
#include "renderHeader.hpp"
using namespace std;

void sayHello(char* name) {
    __renderHeader();
    printf("Hello dear %s, Good evening.", name);
}
```

---

### renderHeader.cpp

```
#include "renderHeader.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void __rendeHeader() {
    printf("This is another shared lib\n");
}
```

---

### main.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "test.hpp"

int main(){
    sayHello("dariush");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(SHARED_LIB_TEST)

add_library(test SHARED test.cpp)

add_library(renderheader SHARED renderHeader.cpp)

add_executable(myapp main.cpp)

SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test renderheader)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myapp test)
```

---

While i am trying to compile with `CMake` it gives me the error that `__renderHeader()` is not defined in `sayHello()`, The output of the command is as follow:

### CMake

```
$ cmake .. && make
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dariush/Desktop/sharedtest/cmake
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/librenderheader.so
[ 33%] Built target renderheader
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o
/home/dariush/Desktop/sharedtest/test.cpp: In function ‘void sayHello(char*)’:
/home/dariush/Desktop/sharedtest/test.cpp:7:20: error: ‘__renderHeader’ was not declared in this scope
     __renderHeader();
                    ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

#### My Question: What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's not CMake that's complaining, it's your compiler... CMake != compiler

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because this was my first time linking with cmake and it gave me the error, so i thought maybe my CMakeLists.txt script had something to do with it and i did't consider something else "bro"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure

```
void __rendeHeader() {
```

should be void __renderHeader() {

Comment: What are the differences between those you suggest??

Comment: Oops!! I am dumb, a miss-spelled!! :)